# Problems using TimePicker with sdk-21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-timepicker

I am trying to use the TimePicker widget in my layout (just dragged it in the design view of Android Studio to my layout), but it does not work, error message:

Couldn't resolve @layout/time_header_label

Failed to parse file /home/user/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-21/data/res/layout/time_picker_holo.xml

I looked at this directory and found time_picker_holo.xml aswell as time_header_label.xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          tools:context="com.myapp.app.ui.EditActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
        <TimePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"/>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add java class + full stacktrace. Your layout is fine. I tried to inflate it and it's working fine

Comment: I have no Class-Code yet and hence no stacktrace. I just added the TimePicker via Drag n Drop in the layout editor from AndroidStudio

Comment: Does your app compile and run ?

Comment: Yes it compiles and runs. But I can not edit it in the design view.

Comment: It happens specially with customs view. You cannot develop on android and avoid to build your layout in xml. However the TimePicker is displayed correctly for me so try to update your IDE

Comment: Sure, I do not want to avoid to build in xml, most of the time I do, but its a benefit to preview the layout without the need of building the app every time. My IDE is the latest Android Studio. Maybe some configuration bug....

Comment: And if you check the SDK manager, you have the last update of every build-tools ? (don't forget to restart android studio)

Comment: Yep, everythings up to date...